# Finding vertices of a triangle using complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles

[image: The diagram shows an equilateral triangle with its centre at the origin and one vertex A (4,-1)]

The question wants me to find the coordinates of the other two vertices B and C.

What I did was that I converted A into complex coordinates, so 4-i.

Then I want to find vertex B, and I know that equilaterial triangle, each angle is $60 ^{\circ}$, so I did $(4-i)cis(\pi/3)$

The steps are as follows: 
$(4-i)cis(\pi/3)=(4-i)[cos(\pi/3)+isin(\pi/3)]=(4-i)(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i)=2+2\sqrt(3)i-\frac12 i+\frac{\sqrt(3)}{2}$

So the coordinates of B becomes $(\frac{4+\sqrt3}{2}, \frac{4\sqrt3-1}2)$, but the answer given to this question says it's $(\frac{\sqrt3-4}{2}, \frac{4\sqrt3+1}2)$. Where did I go wrong?

To find vertex C, I have also used a similar method, but multiplying 4-i with $cis(-\frac{\pi}{3}). However, I have also gotten a slightly wrong answer involving the signs.

Please advise. Sorry in advance for any mistakes in labelling of the title and tags (I'm not very good at those, but am trying to improve on it)

Comment: Are three vertices equidistant from the origin? from the diagram it looks so, but you didn't mention it. If so you want $(4-i)\cos (2\pi/3)$ because you are rotating it by $120^{\circ}$ about the center.

Comment: i don't think the problem as posed has a unique solution. you need more constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the center of the triangle is the origin $z=0$, to get from $A$ to $B$ you should rotate by $120$ degrees - or $2\pi /3$ radians.

To see this, connect the origin $O$ to both points $A$ and $B$ and try to see what the angle is between $OA$ and $OB$.